# Why can rails create record by passing realted record, but not related record's id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

```
partners.rb
module Partners
  def self.table_name_prefix
    "partners_"
  end
end

partner.rb
class Partner < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products, through: :partners_products
  has_many :partners_devices, class_name: 'Partners::Device', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :devices, through: :partners_devices

partners/device.rb
class Partners::Device < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :partner
  belongs_to :device
end

device.rb
class Device < ApplicationRecord
  validates :group, presence: true
end


Loading development environment (Rails 7.0.4)
irb(main):001:0> Partner.first.id
  Partner Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "partners".* FROM "partners" ORDER BY "partners"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
"0169ed39-6579-48e5-a182-171fcb0e93de"

irb(main):002:0> Device.first.id
  Device Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "devices".* FROM "devices" ORDER BY "devices"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
"3bd9e6ae-bb37-4cd1-9bb4-19876bf85f68"

irb(main):004:0> Partners::Device.new(partner: Partner.first, device: Device.first).valid?
  Partner Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "partners".* FROM "partners" ORDER BY "partners"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Device Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "devices".* FROM "devices" ORDER BY "devices"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Partners::Device Exists? (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "partners_devices" WHERE "partners_devices"."id" IS NULL LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
true

irb(main):005:0> pd = Partners::Device.new(partner_id: Partner.first.id, device_id: Device.first.id).valid?
  Partner Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "partners".* FROM "partners" ORDER BY "partners"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Device Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "devices".* FROM "devices" ORDER BY "devices"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Partners::Device Exists? (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "partners_devices" WHERE "partners_devices"."id" IS NULL LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Partner Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "partners".* FROM "partners" WHERE "partners"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "0169ed39-6579-48e5-a182-171fcb0e93de"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Partners::Device Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "partners_devices".* FROM "partners_devices" WHERE "partners_devices"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "3bd9e6ae-bb37-4cd1-9bb4-19876bf85f68"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
false

irb(main):007:0> pd = Partners::Device.new(partner_id: Partner.first.id, device_id: Device.first.id)
  Partner Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "partners".* FROM "partners" ORDER BY "partners"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Device Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "devices".* FROM "devices" ORDER BY "devices"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
#<Partners::Device:0x000000010914e998> {
                 :id => nil,
         :partner_id => "0169ed39-6579-48e5-a182-171fcb0e93de",
          :device_id => "3bd9e6ae-bb37-4cd1-9bb4-19876bf85f68",
                   ....
}
irb(main):012:0> pd.valid?

  Partners::Device Exists? (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "partners_devices" WHERE "partners_devices"."id" IS NULL LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Partner Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "partners".* FROM "partners" WHERE "partners"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "0169ed39-6579-48e5-a182-171fcb0e93de"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Partners::Device Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "partners_devices".* FROM "partners_devices" WHERE "partners_devices"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "3bd9e6ae-bb37-4cd1-9bb4-19876bf85f68"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
false

irb(main):013:0> pd.errors
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x0000000109533338> {
                 "id" => nil,
         "partner_id" => "0169ed39-6579-48e5-a182-171fcb0e93de",
          "device_id" => "3bd9e6ae-bb37-4cd1-9bb4-19876bf85f68",
                   .....
             :details => {
        :device => [
            [0] {
                :error => :blank
            }
        ]
    },
            :messages => {
        :device => [
            [0] "must exist"
        ]
    }
}
```

looking at SQL I see that it checks wether Partners::Device already exists, whether Partner exists aaaaand.... wether Partners::Device exists again, I guess it should check whether Device exists instead.  But cant figure out why.

here >>

```
irb(main):001:0> Partners::Device.new(partner_id: "0169ed39-6579-48e5-a182-171fcb0e93de", device_id: "3bd9e6ae-bb37-4cd1-9bb4-19876bf85f68").valid?
  Partners::Device Exists? (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "partners_devices" WHERE "partners_devices"."id" IS NULL LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Partner Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "partners".* FROM "partners" WHERE "partners"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "0169ed39-6579-48e5-a182-171fcb0e93de"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Partners::Device Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "partners_devices".* FROM "partners_devices" WHERE "partners_devices"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "3bd9e6ae-bb37-4cd1-9bb4-19876bf85f68"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
false
irb(main):002:0>
```

Comment: What is `:group`?

Comment: just a simple string attribute. should be ignored

Comment: I'm thinking this is not a SQL issue, so that tag is probably not needed. I think it has to do with Rails naming expectations. I've not seen it done the way you are doing `partners_devices`. I can't say it's wrong, just not a pattern I'm familiar with. I would normally have a model file called `partner_device.rb` which then defines `class PartnerDevice < ApplicationRecord...` Rails "convention over configuration" depends a lot of naming and structure. I've not see it done this way, but I can't call myself an expert.

Comment: @Beartech yes,  I don't think it's  a SQL issue, just that clue is in SQL. it' looking up in wrong table.  and yes, normally i'd have `partners_address` as a join table. reason I'm trying this out is that there are going to be a lot of tables, controllers, resources etc that have nothing to do with each other. I'm trying to break down repo in separate sections while keeping in same repo/project.  namespacing causes issues, but hey, you dont try - you dont learn/grow

Comment: The first thing you should do here is change the defintion to `module Partner; class Device; ...; end; end`. Using the scope resolution operator is asking for trouble as it doesn't set the module nesting and leads to suprising behavior when looking up constants. https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#namespace-definition

Comment: @max, yep. appreciate it. dont know what I was thinking. I knew I should have module > class, but forget why and decided to go with `Foo::Bar` instead. now I do...  again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I believe your issue might be a namespace lookup problem. You can see this here:

```
SELECT 
  "partners_devices".* 
FROM 
  "partners_devices" 
WHERE "partners_devices"."id" = "3bd9e6ae-bb37-4cd1-9bb4-19876bf85f68"
```

It is trying to lookup the `Partners::Device` by the ID when you are expecting it to look up the `Device` with that ID

I suspect this is because of

```
class Partners::Device < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :partner
  belongs_to :device # This line 
end
```

This equates to

```
belongs_to :device, class_name: 'Device'
```

and inside `Partners::Device` the constant `Device` is `Partners::Device`
e.g.

```
Partners::Device.const_get('Device') #=> Partners::Device
Partners::Device.const_get('::Device') #=> Device
```

So you could change this to:

```
belongs_to :device, class_name: '::Device'
```

Which will use the TOP_LEVEL scope `Device`.

However normal convention would be to use 'models/partners_device.rb' and

```
class PartnersDevice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :partner
  belongs_to :device
end
```

<s>As a sidenote your partners.rb file does not do anything. It simply defines a module method of `::table_name_prefix` but this is never used anywhere for any reason.</s>

The above statement was incorrect because rails made an, in my sole opinion, awful choice to allow nested classes inside a module (or class) to "inherit" the `table_name_prefix` from the "parent". [Source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.4/activerecord/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb#L288)

Comment: oddly enought `Partners::Device.const_get('Device') => Device` but `belongs_to :device, class_name: '::Device'` solves the problem.  Thank you

Comment: There is a giant gotcha here - when you define the class as `class Partners::Device`  the module nesting is `[Partners::Device]` - not `[Partners::Device, Partners]` which will lead to very confusing constant lookups. For example if you do `belongs_to :foo` it will look for the top level `Foo` instead of `Partners::Foo`.

Comment: Also you don't need to set the table name prefix here at all. `Foos::Bar.table_name -> foos_bars`.  And even if you're nesting your classes you should still follow the naming conventions for your assocations `has_many :partner_devices, class_name: 'Partners::Device', dependent: :destroy` - `partners_devices` make me want to have a stroke.

Comment: @max I appreciate additional notes. regarding `partner_devices` vs `partners_devices`  usually I follow convention that if its just one table belongs to another I use singular_plural (`partner_devices`) with class `PartnerDevice`, but if its a  join table between Partner and Device I use `partners_device` `PartnersDevice`.  but I'll certainly re-evaluate the benefit of that

Comment: @max regarding `Foos::Bar.table_name` without partners.rb file it just gives me 'devices'. I cant reproduce what you suggest

Comment: @AndreiMotinga you're doing something very strange if thats the case. I just tested `irb(main):002:0> Partners::Device.table_name => "partners_devices"` in Rails 7.01 and thats how it's worked for a very long time. Its very unlikely that ActiveRecord would change how it derives table names.

Comment: Are you even sure you're referencing the correct constant for example?

Comment: @max he may have taken your suggestion of `module Partners; class Device < ApplicationRecord; end; end`. In this case `Partners::Device.table_name #=> 'devices'`. Per the docs for rails 2 though 7 *"Nested classes are given table names prefixed by the singular form of the parent's table name. **Enclosing modules are not considered.**"*. Now if the class was actually named `class Partners::Device < ApplicationRecord; end;` (as in the original post) then you are correct because `Partners` is no longer an enclosing module.

Comment: @engineersmnky I think the docs might actually be wrong - the table name is derived from the class name via [ActiveModel::Naming#plural](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Naming.html#method-c-plural) so the module nesting doesn't actually matter. I tested it out and there is no difference depending on how you nest the class.

Comment: @engineersmnky Yeah the documentation is definately wrong or just confused- modules are not ignored  https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7c70791470fc517deb7c640bead9f1b47efb5539/activerecord/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb#L621

Comment: @max going to disagree with you in practice, although I was wrong as well. `Partners::Device.table_name #=> 'devices'` where `Partners` is a `Module`. [Example](https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/RailsTableNamesNested#main.rb) I have no idea how the original code decided this table was `partners_devices`

Comment: I found it (stupid rails magic) if a class is nested and the "parent" defines `table_name_prefix` then it will be "inherited" as part of the table name [Here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7c70791470fc517deb7c640bead9f1b47efb5539/activerecord/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb#L288). What an awful bastardization.

Comment: @engineersmnky nice, I went down the rabbit hole of actually writing a test from the bug report template and  I was going crazy since I could get the test to behave the same way as the code generated in my app. That explains it.